# verificar se arquivo esta em uso com php

Tags: php, cron

Galera tenho um arquivo chamado foto.zip, onde as pessoas podem baixar ele no meu site. Quero criar um arquivo em php que o crontab vai rodar a cada 10 minutos, e verifica se o arquivo esta sendo baixado por alguém. Se não estiver ele apaga o arquivo.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso.

Comment: Só uma sugestão @Hugo: coloca no título da pergunta **verificar com php se existe um download em andamento**. Normalmente o termo **arquivo em uso** é utilizado para designar um arquivo aberto por uma aplicação do sistema operacional que pode não ser um download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, devemos saber qual é o teu servidor.

Se for apache, você deve acessar esta [seção da documentação (access logs)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) e verificar qual o arquivo de acessos.

Se for IIS, acessa esta [seção da documentação](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc730608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) e vê onde estão os arquivos de log. Pelo que você postou acredito que não seja este.

Em ambos os casos, tem que checar se a versão do teu servidor está de acordo com a da documentação que sugeri.

O segundo passo é deixar estes logs acessíveis ao para a consulta via php. Por questões de segurança, recomendo que o teu script php da crontab, tire uma cópia deste arquivo para um outro diretório e faça a verificação.

Uma outra alternativa, e acho esta mais recomendada. É você criar na página de acesso um botão que fará uma ação para gerenciar o download do arquivo. Acredito que deva haver um **tratamento php/javaScript/Ajax** de forma que enquanto o download estiver em andamento, gere algum sinalizador (ex. um arquivo do tipo .lock-[date]-[time]) que é apagado após o download ser terminado ou interrompido. Quando o teu programa da crontab rodar e não encontrar nenhum sinalizador, aí ele apaga o arquivo.

Comment: Quanto a esta segunda alternativa, postei uma [questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135611/existe-em-php-uma-forma-para-registrar-o-status-dos-download-de-um-arquivo) para saber se é possível, apenas pelo php/javascript, sem consultar os logs do apache, acumular esta informação. Existem vários sites de download que fazem isso, acredito que deva haver ferramentas client-side já prontas.