# Soluções para contabilizar downloads de um arquivo

Tags: php, apache, download, engenharia-de-software

Supor para este caso o servidor apache e linguagem php.

### O Problema

Eu possuo no meu servidor um arquivo (Ex: **formulario.pdf**) e existe uma página (**formulario.php**) que possui um botão para o download deste arquivo.

Preciso obter as informações periódicas do número de **de downloads com sucesso** de **formulario.pdf** e atualizar a página formulário.php informando esta número.

### Formas de implementação

A questão é qual das formas abaixo é a mais recomendada, levando em consideração a facilidade de implementação e segurança:

1. Consultar periodicamente os logs do servidor referente aos downloads do arquivo (Se é que existe este dado e é seguro fazer isso) e armazenar o valor em uma base;
2. Execução de uma ação em PHP/HTML5/javascript para em cada download, após o término (ou interrupção por algum motivo) serem  registrados um dos seguintes status: sucesso para o download baixado e falha do contrário. O valor ficaria armazenado em uma base de dados.

Lembrando que neste caso a resposta não é necessariamente um codigo-solução para o problema, mas qual das alternativas acima é a mais recomendada (pode haver inclusive uma outra) e neste caso, pode-se usar um código exemplo para ajudar na explicação.

Comment: Esse artigo retrata exatamente o que você precisa e com instruções passo a passo de coo fazê-lo em PHP e MYSql: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Criando-um-contador-de-downloads-com-PHP-e-MySQL

Comment: Seria bom uma resposta, não que o artigo não seja bom, mas links externos costumam desaparecer com o tempo e o SOpt é eterno.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Paulo, ai tem um bom ponto de partida para a solução 2, mas como Florida disse é bom construirmos algo aqui que fica melhor para estudarmos e discutirmos. É bom vermos também um exemplo da solução 1 e compararmos as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja um pouco de preferência pessoal,

Eu particularmente preferiria criar uma tabelinha para armazenar as informações destes downloads, ficaria muito mais fácil para tirar estatísticas ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Esta tabela seria alimentada pelo processamento PHP/javascript do download ou pelos logs do apache? Qual seria sua fonte de dados e como ela seria alimentada?

Comment: Eu trabalharia com um disparo através do javascript e assim que concluído o download faria uma chama ajax para um PHP que inseriria as informações em um banco de dados, como mysql, postgresql ou qualquer outra base. Existe um plugin em jquery chamado fileDownload que ajuda a identificar quando termina

Comment: link do plugin: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload